# Divergence Series

Tags: calculus, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slowing down divergence 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82309/slowing-down-divergence-2)

If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are two increasing sequences of positive numbers such that both $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b_n}$ are divergent. Then is it true that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n+b_n}$ is also divergent?

I think the answer is no, but I cannot come up with an appropriate example. Thanks!